# How to breaking up a string into columns in pandas?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, pandas, data-manipulation

I have a pandas data frame very similar like this (it is actually larger) with two columns:

```
ID       |STRING_COL
ID2309480|#0809890 ^ True ^ ReP  ^ APPLE
ID2398403|#0938409 ^ True ^ POST ^ GOOGLE
ID0398240|#0938402 ^ True ^ POST ^ VERIZON
```

How can I split the `STRING_COL` into:

```
ID       |NUMBER   | VALUE| Accepted| COMPANY
---------------------------------------------
ID2309480|#0809890 | True | ReP     | APPLE
ID2398403|#0938409 | True | POST    | GOOGLE
ID0398240|#0938402 | True | POST    | VERIZON
```

After reading this [tutorial](https://chrisalbon.com/python/pandas_regex_to_create_columns.html) and some other questions of this site I tried to split them like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df.STRING_COL.str.split('^',1).tolist(), columns = ['ID','NUMBER', 'VALUES', 'ACCEPTED', 'COMPANY'])
df
```

But apparently this is wrong, since it returned me the following traceback:

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'str'
```

So, how to split the `STRING_COL` into other chunks taking `^` as a separator?.

**UPDATE**

I also tried this one:

```
df['STRING_COL'].str.split('^', 1, expand=True)
```

But I do not understand how to add the other columns..

Answer (score 2):

This should give you what you want in `df3`. I used the `pd.concat` method to append the proper columns into a single df.

```
# Using your second method to split the second column (slight variation)
df2 = df['STRING_COL'].str.split('^', expand=True)

# Concatenate the proper columns into a single df
df3 = pd.concat([df[['ID']], df2], axis=1)

# Rename the columns and turn the VALUE column into type bool 
df3.columns = ['ID', 'NUMBER', 'VALUE', 'Accepted', 'COMPANY']
df3.VALUE = df3.VALUE.astype(bool)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your second approach was on the right track - from there iterate and assign the columns - something like this:

```
names = ['NUMBER', 'VALUE', 'Accepted', 'Company']

new_cols = df['STRING_COL'].str.split('^', expand=True)

for i, name in enumerate(names):
    df[name] = new_cols[i]

df
Out[43]: 
          ID                        STRING_COL     NUMBER   VALUE Accepted  \
0  ID2309480    #0809890 ^ True ^ ReP  ^ APPLE  #0809890    True     ReP     
1  ID2398403   #0938409 ^ True ^ POST ^ GOOGLE  #0938409    True     POST    
2  ID0398240  #0938402 ^ True ^ POST ^ VERIZON  #0938402    True     POST    

    Company  
0     APPLE  
1    GOOGLE  
2   VERIZON
```